# FIREBASE REST connect once and multiple write will not change data in firebase

Tags: firebase

I am new to firebase and I want to add firebase into my project. I wrote a piece of java code to test the feature related to my project. It is about REST put data.
My issue is, if I create new connection everytime I put data, the data at firebase will change and trigger the binded function. If I only create the connection once, and
write the data to firebase using this connection, the binded function will be only triggered once(the very first data immediately after the connection is open). The thing is there
are a lot of data to put and it will degrade the performance if I new/open the connection everytime. Is there way to solve this problem? Or maybe it is not a problem but what I did
 was not correct. Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks.
Here is the code:

```
    String httpsURL = "https://xxxx.firebaseio.com/users.json";
    URL myurl = new URL(httpsURL);
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)myurl.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("PUT");
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setDoInput(true);

    DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());  

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("first", "xxx");
    json.put("last", "yyy");        
    System.out.println(json.toString());
    output.writeBytes(json.toString());
    output.flush();        

    json.put("first", "aaa");
    json.put("last", "bbbb");        
    System.out.println(json.toString());
    output.writeBytes(json.toString());
    output.flush();

    json.put("first", "eee");
    json.put("last", "rrrr");        
    System.out.println(json.toString());
    output.writeBytes(json.toString());
    output.flush();
    input = new DataInputStream( con.getInputStream() );
    for( int c = input.read(); c != -1; c = input.read() )
    System.out.print( (char)c );

    System.out.println("Resp Code:"+con .getResponseCode());
    System.out.println("Resp Message:"+ con .getResponseMessage());
    input.close();
    output.close();
    con.disconnect();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're sending a single HTTP PUT request with multiple chunks of data.

You need to send one HTTP request for every piece of data you want to write. This doesn't mean you have to re-establish a TCP connection. It just means you need to construct and send a new HTTP request with the new blob of data.

You'll also probably want to write to a different URL for each request (or use POST) so that you don't overwrite your existing data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you mean that I need to call HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)myurl.openConnection(); everytime for each http request?

Comment: Upon re-reading your code / my answer, I'm not actually sure. I'm not familiar enough with that Java API. Sorry!

Comment: If I call HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)myurl.openConnection(); everytime, it will succeed. However, the performance is degraded because of that.