# Firebase-javascript API get data-nodes satisfying a condition in one trigger only. Also does the makes new TCP connection for each query?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16885793/firebase-rest-connect-once-and-multiple-write-will-not-change-data-in-firebase). However its related to REST and I want to ask regarding javascript-API . Also my case is bit different. So maybe someone can suggest some other solution. 
I want to perform a query similar to this:

```
"SELECT * FROM db.table WHERE field1 ="val1";"
```

With firebase we can do following:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://db.firebaseio.com/table");
ref.orderByChild("field1").equalTo("val1").on("value", function(record) {
  console.log(record.val())
});
```

So firebase triggers my callback function for each child that satisfies field1="val1". Does it opens new TCP connection for each of these chlid queries? Also is there any way to get all the childs satisfying the condition just in one go(That is one callback is triggered when all of them are downloaded at the client).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So firebase triggers my callback function for each child that satisfies field1="val1"

Not exactly. It triggers the callback function exactly once, passing all the matching nodes in the DataSnapshot parameter. You can loop over them with:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://db.firebaseio.com/table");
ref.orderByChild("field1").equalTo("val1").on("value", function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(record) {
    console.log(record.val())
  });
});
```

The loop is needed, even if there's only one child. You can use [`snapshot.numChildren()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/datasnapshot/numchildren.html) to determine if there are *any* nodes matching your query.

> Does it opens new TCP connection for each of these chlid queries

Nope. The Firebase client establishes a WebSocket connection when you first call `new Firebase(...)`. After that all communication goes over that WebSocket. Only when the environment doesn't support WebSockets, does Firebase fall back to HTTP long-polling. Have a look in the network tab of your browser's debugger to see what's going over the wire. It's quite educational.

> Also is there any way to get all the childs satisfying the condition just in one go(That is one callback is triggered when all of them are downloaded at the client).

I think I answered that one already.

### Update based on the comments

> Are the callback functions passed to forEach called synchronously?

Yes

Comment: Thanks. I also went through Firebase documentations. But it was not clear. Are the callback functions passed to forEach called synchronously? i.e it will be called for child 2 only after it returned for child 1. Basically I want to collect some data from all the childs and then pass it to some-one. I could think of a way i.e counting(globally) how many childs have done yet in the callback itself and check if thats == snapshot.numChildren() then do the stuff. But is it possible to do it synchronously?